# Is there a way to have a dataframe return groupings per week?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe that has information presented like the table below, date is my Index:

```
date      | Company | Industry    | Focus
2020-08-02  Ford      Auto           Cars
2020-08-02  Pizza Hut Restaurant     Food
2020-08-03  Tesla     Auto           Cars
2020-08-04  Honda     Auto           Cars
2020-08-04  KFC       Restaurant     Food
2020-08-05  Marathon  Energy         Oil&Gas
2020-08-05  PSE&G     Energy         Oil&Gas
2020-08-06  Modells   Consumer       Retail
2020-08-07  Macys     Consumer       Retail
2020-08-08  JcPenney  Consumer       Retail
2020-08-09  Toys R Us Consumer       Retail
2020-08-10  JP Morgan Financial      Bank
2020-08-11  Greenwood Financial      Real Estate 
2020-08-12  RCH Pharm Health Care    Pharmacy 
2020-08-12  RBJ Hosp. Health Care    Hospital
2020-08-13  Applebees Restaurant     Food
2020-08-14  Sleepys   Consumer       Retail
```

I am looking for a result that will yield me a dataframe that groups the total amount of companies per industry on a weekly basis, with Saturday being the end of a week.

```
date       | Auto | Restaurant | Energy | Consumer | Financial | Health Care| Total
2020-08-08    3       2           2         3            0          0         10
2020-08-15    0       1           0         2            2          2         7
```

I have tried:

```
df.groupby(['Industry']).resample('W-SAT').count()
```

but this results in Industry becoming another index.

Comment: `df['Industry'].resample('W-SAT').value_counts()`?

Comment: that draws an error unfortunately

Comment: you can just unstack after and select a column `df.groupby(['Industry'])['Industry'].resample('W-SAT').count().unstack(0)`

Comment: @Ben.T brilliant, exactly what i wanted, thanks!